# Why my created random function just work for one time?

Tags: c#, random

Thank you for helping me!

There is a piece of **random function** I found on the Internet, called `GetRandom`. I put it like below

```
 public static double GetRandom(double[] array)
　　{    
　      Random ran = new Random();
　　　　int n = ran.Next(array.Length);
　　　　return array[n];
　　}

 private void Window_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {   


        c1 = c-GetRandom(arr);
        c2 = c-GetRandom(arr);
......

    }
```

arr is a double arry containing a a few doubles. c1,c2,c3 .... are all double. Howeve, it seems that every **GetRandom(arr)** in the last few lines return the same result.How come? The **n** in `GetRandom` can't be refreshed after each use?

Comment: You don't need many Randoms. One `Random` can generate infinite random numbers.

Comment: The official documentation describes this behavior.  Consult it often.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need move create Random outside function by create `Random ran = new Random();` in class scope.

```
 Random ran = new Random();
 public static double GetRandom(double[] array, Random ran)
    　　{     
    　　　　int n = ran.Next(array.Length);
    　　　　return array[n];
    　　}

private void Window_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {   

        c1 = c-GetRandom(arr, ran);
        c2 = c-GetRandom(arr, ran);

    }
```

Comment: I updated answer move out random as class scope, remove vote down please